# NHibernate Criteria Subquery help

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I am using NHibernate and I my requirement is that I have 2 tables, User and Ticket. I want all the records that are in User but not in Ticket. The Ticket table has UserId as reference key to the Primary key ID of User table. Below is my code,

```
 RegNotTickTemplate.Criteria = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(User));
            RegNotTickTemplate.Criteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyNotIn("ID",DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(Ticket))
                .SetProjection(Projections.Property("UserID"))));
```

The above query doesnt return correct set of records.

Comment: i've used this type of subquery countless times, i can't seem to see something wrong... maybe post some additional info, maybe even the generated sql?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could try using HQL.  I never use Criteria as I find HQL more readable (it is almost the same as SQL except you get to query based on the entities rather than the tables).

[Chapter 13. HQL: The Hibernate Query Language](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql)

```
IQuery query = Session.CreateQuery(
       "from User where Id not in (select UserId from Ticket)");
       query.List<User>();
```

If that is still no good, you can always do an SQL query

```
ISQLQuery query = Session.CreateSQLQuery(sql);
```

Comment: I would really want to use Criteria Query as thats the way how the app is set up to work. Any help with that would be great..

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is: the count of tickets for this user should be greater than zero. Here is how you can implement it:

```
RegNotTickTemplate.Criteria = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(User));
RegNotTickTemplate.Criteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id",
          DetachedCriteria.For<Ticket>()
            .SetProjection(Projections.GroupProperty("User"))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.RowCount(), 0))));
```

If you don't want the count of rows you can do the following:

```
RegNotTickTemplate.Criteria = DetachedCriteria.For(typeof(User),"user");
RegNotTickTemplate.Criteria.Add(Subqueries.Exists(DetachedCriteria.For<Ticket>("ticket")
            .SetProjection(Projections.Property("User"))
            .Add(Restrictions.EqProperty("user.Id", "User"))));
```